# The position of legs while sitting on a chair

Tags: vocabulary

How can we describe the legs' position in the picture below?

His legs are... from the chair.

He is sitting on a chair with legs...

What should be the adjectives to complete these sentences?

[image]

Comment: For what purpose?  Are you writing instructions on how to sit exactly like this, and so need lots of detail, or are you describing the general posture, and can be quite vague.  You see general posture is the normal way of sitting in a chair, so you would not generally need to say anything.

Comment: yes for instructions

Comment: Then you need more than one word.  His knees are angled at between 100 and 120 degrees with his thighs horizontal. His feet are resting on a footrest with the foot perpendicular to the shin.